# No glyphicon output in Angular with bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to output a *glyphicon-star*. I have installed bootstrap and I created a component called *favorite* using angular cli. This is the content of my *favorite.component.html*

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
```

Following is the content of my *favorite.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'favorite',
  templateUrl: './favorite.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favorite.component.css']
})
export class FavoriteComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and following is the content of my *app.component.html*

```
<favorite></favorite>
```

Sometimes I get *[WDS] Disconnected!* error. But I'm not getting the desired output.
I've tried executing *npm update*

P.S : When I try to display a primary button, it works fine.

Comment: _I have installed bootstrap_; What have you done after `npm i bootstrap`?

Comment: @pzaenger I did ````npm install bootstrap --save````  and added ````@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"```` to styles.css

Comment: did you had added the bootstrap css file to styles array in `angular.json` file

Answer (score 1):

You have to add bootstrap styles minfied file into styles array in `angular.json`

`{
  ...
  "projects": {
  "contactsapp": {
    ...
    "architect": {
        "build": {
         ...
        "styles": [
           "src/styles.css",
           "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ...`

Comment: When I try this I get this error ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css) Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js): Error: Failed to find 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' in [ c:\D\angular\hello-world\src ] at c:\D\angular\hello-world\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13 at async Promise.all (index 0)

Comment: if you installed  npm bootstrap like you mentioned int he comments you have to add the path of minified file like this 
`"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: I added that to the angular.json file

Comment: try to  Add `../ `before path.
to be 
`"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Comment: Q: Where exactly under node_modules do you see `bootstrap.min.css`?  Is it there at all?  If so, please tell us the path.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install Bootstrap and jQuery

   EXAMPLE:

   ```
   cd myProject
   npm install --save bootstrap jquery
   ```
2. Update angular.json:

   EXAMPLE:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "projects": {
     "contactsapp": {
       ...
       "architect": {
           "build": {
            ...
           "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
               ...
           "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
           ]
   ```
3. Use Bootstrap in your templates

   EXAMPLE: favorite.component.html

   ```
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
   ```

If you're still having problems/questions, I found this tutorial helpful:

[Styling An Angular Application With Bootstrap, Ahmed Bouchefra](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/02/angular-application-bootstrap/)

Comment: When I try this I get this error 
./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
  in [
    c:\D\angular\hello-world\src
  ]
    at c:\D\angular\hello-world\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13
    at async Promise.all (index 0)

Comment: Check your `node_modules` folder. If you installed jquery and bootstrap per above, you should have that file.  If you installed it differently, either delete and reinstall, or adjust the paths

Answer (score -1):

The code doesn't work with bootstrap 4 but works fine with bootstrap 3.3.7.

Comment: Bootstap 4 should work  fine with Angular... if you install it correctly, using npm. Q: What version of Angular are you using (I most recently used it with Angular 8)?  Q: Did you find where Bootstrap and jQuery installed under your node_modules?

Comment: @FoggyDay Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 12.14.0
Angular: 8.2.14

The bootstrap and jQuery installed properly where they were supposed to be installed.

Comment: Hi - 1) "solving" a problem by backing down to an older version is often absolutely necessary. But in general, you should only do it as a last resort.  2) If you did `npm install --save bootstrap jquery` in your project root directory, then you *should* have a `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/* subdirectory, and you should  be able to access anything in it from your project's templates and stylesheets.